# View not getting displayed using angular6

Tags: angular6

[image]
[image]
[image]

Below is the view i am getting instead of element displaying in the view.
Only the headers are getting displayed.
I am getting the values in console.

i am pretty new to angular framework

Comment: Added .html,.ts and the view page which i am getting now

Answer (score 0):

I think problem at

```
[dataSource]="library_management_system"
```

It would be

```
[dataSource]="library"
```

Comment: You're welcome! You can accept and thumbs up to increase my reputation :)

Answer (score 0):

Going through your console in the image , you should simply use

{{library._id}}
{{library.title}}

instead of

{{element.author}}